# Yii : "[templates col=2]" What is this?

Tags: php, yii

I am new Yii framework I am currently working on a website, come across this "[templates col=2]" in a file. I dont know what this exactly do. Please tell me what this code does?

Comment: It is probably a shortcode. May be a component is created by someone (NOT Yii)

Comment: @Think Different How to know how it was created and  where it is?

Comment: You have to check your application directory structure. Mostly it would be either in the Components folder or under vendor folder. Expand all your directories and print screen the results and post it here with files and folders visible, if you still struggling to find out